# Deserialize interface to concrete type in RESTEasy API with Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, resteasy

I have an interface implemented by a series of classes, and I want to set it as an argument in a RESTEasy endpoint:

```
public interface HasName {
    ...
}

public class Bean implements HasName {
    ...
}

@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Bean create(HasName thing);
```

How could I instruct Jackson to deserialize `HasName` to `Bean`? I found [JsonTypeResolver](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonTypeResolver.html), whose description sounds like what I want, but I can't figure out how to use it.

NOTE: I don't want to annotate the interface so that it's always deserialized to the same concrete class, I want to be able to deserialize it to different classes in different endpoints.

Comment: Are there times where `create()`'s argument would need to be different than `Bean` object, ie. a different `HasName` implementation?

Comment: Όχι. I mean, no :) There might be other RESTEasy endpoints in the application that will, for example `create()` different kinds of objects, but each one will have a defined concrete class.